# Compositor and Greenscreen video with 3D Background

Tags: compositing-nodes

I was removing the greenscreen of a video in the compositor. But I don't understand how I make the video show up in the 3D Scene.

I tried Import Images as Planes but it still is showing with the greenscreen.

How can I make it show without the greenscreen?

Comment: Using the 3D view isn't really the common way to composite 2D data on each other, that's the compositor's job. You can use the Render Layer node to get your 3D scene in the compositor.